# Need Hive equivalent of oracle's regexp_extract to extract text between patterns

Tags: regex, hive, extract, equivalent

My data looks like this:

```
bizunit
nam-bu1-us-credit
nam-bu2-us-debit
latam-bu3-mx-debit
```

Now I want to extract `nam` & `latam` into a separate column called `region` and extract `bu1`, `bu2`, `bu3` into a separate column called `business unit` and `us`, `mx` into a separate column called `country`.

What hive function and SQL would I use? Please share a sample hive SQL to split the above data into 3 columns to be extracted as above.

Comment: Please provide desired output dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE myTably(
  myText string
  )
INSERT INTO TABLE concat_test VALUES 
  ('nam-bu1-us-credit'), 
  ('nam-bu2-us-debit'), 
  ('latam-bu3-mx-debit');
```

Here's the query to extract region, business unit and country

```
select 
regexp_extract(myText, '([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-', 1),
regexp_extract(myText, '([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-', 2),
regexp_extract(myText, '([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-', 3) from MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used below function and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: select split(column,'pattern')[column number] from table;

Comment: That works too! Glad you are sorted out!

Comment: Hello Matt. Quick Q - my table name is case. As it's a keyword, my sql is failing despite using the ` sign on both sides  of the table name (the sign on the tilde key on the keyboard), any suggestions? Thank you again in advance

Comment: As a table name, I'm not sure you can try this setting hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false but really I'd suggest you pick a different name, someone else might start having issues as your table will suddenly be in a different context for them. (If someone else uses case in their query)